# PHP to add a formula to a column in excel with xlsxwriter

Tags: php, excel, xlsxwriter

i can put =MAX(K2,L2,M2,O2,P2,Q2,N2) in cell F2 with a xlsxwriter no problem but i can't get it to change for each row (i.e  =MAX(K2,L2,M2,O2,P2,Q2,N2) in cell F2)

so if i had a thousand rows it would go to  (i.e  =MAX(K1000,L1000,M1000,O1000,P10002,Q2,N1000) in cell F1000) (BestPrice is row F)

this is the code i have  is in PHP 5.3.24

...

```
$resulted[$y] = array('ISBN' => $isbn,
                  'Quantity' => $qty,
                  'Title' => $shortTitle,
                  'ItemAmount'=>$amount,
                  'Best'=>$best,
                  'BestPrice'=> '=MAX(K2,L2,M2,O2,P2,Q2,N2)',
                  'Difference'=>'=E-H',
                  'AvaQty'=>$AvaQty,
                  'LastDate'=>$LastDate,
                  'LastPrice'=>$LastPrice,
                                         );
$y++;
}


$header =  array('ISBN' => 'integer',
                  'Quantity' => 'integer',
                  'Title' => 'string',
                  'Item_Amount'=>'price',
                  'Best' =>'string',
                  'BestPrice'=> 'price',

                  'Difference'=>'price',

                  'AvaQty'=>'integer',
                  'LastDate'=>'date',
                  'LastPrice'=>'price',


                   );

$col_options=array('widths'=> array(40, 10,40,10));
$writer = new XLSXWriter();

$writer->writeSheetHeader('Name', $header, $col_options);
foreach($resulted as $row)
$writer->writeSheetRow('Name', $row);
$writer->writeToFile("../My".$tracking .".xlsx");
```

any thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use a variable to track your row numbers.  Depending on what `$y` is, you may be able to use that.  If not, something like this will work:

```
$y = 0;
$row = 2;
foreach($book_list as $book){ //Assuming you have some kind of book list you're iterating over...
    //Doing some stuff (e.g. setting those variables you use in the array)

    $resulted[$y] = array('ISBN' => $isbn,
      'Quantity' => $qty,
      'Title' => $shortTitle,
      'ItemAmount'=>$amount,
      'Best'=>$best,
      'BestPrice'=> "=MAX(K{$row},L{$row},M{$row},O{$row},P{$row},Q{$row},N{$row})", //Note the change in this line.
      'Difference'=>'=E-H',
      'AvaQty'=>$AvaQty,
      'LastDate'=>$LastDate,
      'LastPrice'=>$LastPrice,
    );
    $y++;
    $row++;
}
```

I' suspect you will be able to use `$y` for this instead of a separate variable, assuming it is just a 0-indexed counter you could do something like `$row = $y+2` at the beginning of the loop iteration.  Regardless, this should point you in the right direction